# How to make a GET request in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, api, get, request

I'm writing an Oauth2 script, and I've got stuck at the token GET request.

It's a Fitbit Oauth2 script, so the script takes my App ID, secret and callback URI.

It then gives me a link with a token at the end, I am struggling to work out how to grab the token and store it in my app.

Here is my code for connecting to FitBit, which works fine, I just don't know how to grab the 'token' at the end of the received URL.

[Oauth2 Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv5Zv.png)

Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: Please always put the code inside your question, not inside a separate link.

Comment: Do you have to open the link inside Safari? Because I'm not sure if you can access anything then. You could maybe make a get request using `URLSession` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alamofire.request method parameter defaults to .get.

Brief Example

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get") // method defaults to `.get`
```

Detailed Example

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print(response.request)  // original URL request
    print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
    print(response.data)     // server data
    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```